# Javascript para validação

Tags: javascript

Estou usando javascript para validar alguns campos do formulário como telefone e CPF. O script funciona corretamente da forma que eu quero, o problema é que quando o usuário não digita todos os números da maskara o script não limpa o input, ele aceita aquela quantidade de números.

Façam o teste

```js
function inputHandler(masks, max, event) {
 var c = event.target;
 var v = c.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
 var m = c.value.length > max ? 1 : 0;
 VMasker(c).unMask();
 VMasker(c).maskPattern(masks[m]);
 c.value = VMasker.toPattern(v, masks[m]);
}

var telMask = ['(99) 9999-99999', '(99) 99999-9999'];
var tel = document.querySelector('input[attrname=telephone1]');
VMasker(tel).maskPattern(telMask[0]);
tel.addEventListener('input', inputHandler.bind(undefined, telMask, 14), false);

var docMask = ['999.999.999-999', '99.999.999/9999-99'];
var doc = document.querySelector('#doc');
VMasker(doc).maskPattern(docMask[0]);
doc.addEventListener('input', inputHandler.bind(undefined, docMask, 14), false);
```

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}  
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-masker/1.1.0/vanilla-masker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sandro Alvares -->
<div>
<label for="tel">Telefone</label>
<input attrname="telephone1" type="text">
<br><div>
<label for="doc">CPF/CNPJ</label>
<input id="doc" type="text">
```

Eu queria uma ajuda pra fazer com que se o usuário não digitasse a quantidade correta de números, quando ele tirasse o foco o input apagasse os números digitados.

Comment: Acredito eu que a mascara de CPF esteja errada! Ou é impressão minha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escrevi esse método, mas creio que exista uma maneira mais dinâmica.

```
function limpaCampo(event) {
  var value = event.target.value,
      tamanhoA, tamanhoB;
  if (event.target.id === 'tel') {
    tamanhoA = telMask[0].length;
    tamanhoB = telMask[1].length;
  }
  if (event.target.id === 'doc') {
    tamanhoA = docMask[0].length;
    tamanhoB = docMask[1].length;
  }
  if (value.length < tamanhoA || value.length > tamanhoA && value.length < tamanhoB) {
    event.target.value = '';
  }
}

tel.addEventListener('blur', limpaCampo);
doc.addEventListener('blur', limpaCampo);
```

Fiz as seguintes modificações:

1. Adicionei o atributo `id` no campo telefone.

   ```
   <input id="tel" attrname="telephone1" type="text">
   ```
2. Modificado o seletor no JavaScript.

   ```
   var tel = document.querySelector('#tel');
   ```
3. Modificado também as mascaras que estavam com o número de dígitos errados.

   ```
   var telMask = ['(99) 9999-99999', '(99) 99999-9999'];
   var docMask = ['999.999.999-999', '99.999.999/9999-99'];
   ```

   Para:

   ```
   var telMask = ['(99) 9999-9999', '(99) 99999-9999'];
   var docMask = ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'];
   ```

#### Veja funcionando:

```js
function inputHandler(masks, max, event) {
  var c = event.target;
  var v = c.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var m = c.value.length > max ? 1 : 0;
  current_mask = masks[m];
  VMasker(c).unMask();
  VMasker(c).maskPattern(masks[m]);
  c.value = VMasker.toPattern(v, masks[m]);
}

function limpaCampo(event) {
  var value = event.target.value,
      tamanhoA, tamanhoB;
  if (event.target.id === 'tel') {
    tamanhoA = telMask[0].length;
    tamanhoB = telMask[1].length;
  }
  if (event.target.id === 'doc') {
    tamanhoA = docMask[0].length;
    tamanhoB = docMask[1].length;
  }
  if (value.length < tamanhoA || value.length > tamanhoA && value.length < tamanhoB) {
    event.target.value = '';
  }
}

var telMask = ['(99) 9999-9999', '(99) 99999-9999'];
var docMask = ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'];
var tel = document.querySelector('#tel');
var doc = document.querySelector('#doc');

VMasker(tel).maskPattern(telMask[0]);
VMasker(doc).maskPattern(docMask[0]);

tel.addEventListener('input', inputHandler.bind(undefined, telMask, 14), false);
doc.addEventListener('input', inputHandler.bind(undefined, docMask, 14), false);

tel.addEventListener('blur', limpaCampo);
doc.addEventListener('blur', limpaCampo);
```

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}  
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-masker/1.1.0/vanilla-masker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sandro Alvares -->
<div>
<label for="tel">Telefone</label>
<input id="tel" attrname="telephone1" type="text">
<br><div>
<label for="doc">CPF/CNPJ</label>
<input id="doc" type="text">
```

Comment: eu to usando JSF e agora que fui por aqui pra testar, não ta funcionando a função de limpar os campos...

Comment: o problema pode estar nos parâmetros do if, pois substituí o seu conteúdo por um alert e não funcionou

Comment: não, eu fiz só pra testar!! eu só quero que limpe os campos mesmos. Seguinte, como falei eu suspeitei que o if não estava funcionando por conta dos parâmetros. Então eu substituí o parâmetro todo para if (value.length < 14) (no caso cpf) e funcionou. Mas eu sei que não vai ser cômodo quando eu for usar para cpf, telefone, pois do seu jeito usando switch case era bem mais prático. Então eu suspeito que o problema seja o "tamanhoA" e "tamanhoB" que não está funcionando... tu acha o que?

Comment: Se o código é o mesmo daqui não daria erro, mas veja se esta retornando algum erro no console, você mudou o *HTML* também? Igual esta aqui na resposta ?

Comment: jsf é fresco dms

Comment: mudei pq uso jsf... mas os id continua o mesmo

Comment: Veja editei, agora usando `if` veja se funciona.

Comment: Não... eu suspeito que seja o "tamanhoA" que não está recebendo o valor correto para poder comparar. Mas não sei também. Você já ajudou muito. Agradeço

Comment: Então antes de `if (value.length < tamanhoA` consulte se a variavel está recebendo o valor. `console.log(tamanhoA);`